# Table attribute in MVC 4 is not recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model like the following:

```
[Table("forms", Schema = "mySchema")]
public class forms
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string field1 { get; set; }
  public string field2 { get; set; }
}
```

This works in MVC 3, however in MVC 4 the attribute Table in not recognized. I have the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace included, and the dll referenced, along with EntityFramework.dll. The version of EF has changed between MVC 3 and 4. If I reference the MVC 3 EF dll, Table is recognized, however Schema is not. The reason for using the table attribute is so I can specify the schema. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to msdn the [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx) supports the schema property.

Maybe use:

```
[Table(Name = "forms", Schema = "mySchema")]
```

Comment: That is basically what I'm using, though Name = "forms" is not valid. The way I have it is correct. However you linked to the msdn which says you need the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace. Now the table attribute and schema is recognized. Thanks.